# get location coordinates without GPS

Tags: android, kotlin, gps, android-support-library, android-gps

My question is can you get location coordinates latitude and longitude using WIFI or any other source when location is off or disabled. Basically I want to get current location when the GPS is not enabled

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: see above for getting access to coarse / network location data

Answer (score 0):

If location permission isn't granted or location settings are off, no.  That's on purpose-  the user doesn't want to give you their location, respect that.  Now if it's just GPS but not location that's off you can use coarse location.  That uses wifi only, is less accurate, but can be used with less battery drain than GPS.

Comment: can you share code